# restrict date range from datepicker by comparing db dates using laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datepicker

I have two datepickers. one for 'fromDate' and another for 'ToDate'. Here i want to save candidates work Experiences.So i have to fields to add fromdate and todate.That i get more experience history of one candidate.If i choose a date from fromDate picker and ToDate picker it should restrict the selection of dates between the records of db date given in fromdate and todate.In my form i have a check box to check the present work.so i get fromdate of work and todate is set it as 0000-00-00 to know it is on going.
table structure:userid,title,fromdate,todate,company,description.
my code:

```
 <form id="candiwork" action="{{url('Candidate/experience/details')}}" method="post">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <span class="pf-title">Job Title</span>
                            <div class="pf-field">
                                <input placeholder="Job Title.." type="text" name="job" id="job">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <span class="pf-title">From Date</span>
                                <div class="pf-field">
                                    <input placeholder="06.11.2007" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="fromDate" id="fromDate">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <span class="pf-title">To Date</span>
                                <div class="pf-field">
                                    <input placeholder="06.11.2012" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="toDate" id="toDate">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <p class="remember-label">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="fgfg"><label for="fgfg">Present</label>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <span class="pf-title">Company</span>
                                <div class="pf-field">
                                    <input placeholder="Company" type="text" name="company" id="company">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <span class="pf-title">Description</span>
                                <div class="pf-field">
                                    <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <button type="submit" id="btn">Save</button> <br><br><br><br><br><br>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#fromDate").datepicker({
    maxDate: '0',
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    todayBtn:  1,
    autoclose: true,
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('#toDate').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
    $('#toDate').datepicker('setDate', minDate); // <--THIS IS THE LINE ADDED
});

$("#toDate").datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        var maxDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        $('#fromDate').datepicker('setEndDate', maxDate);
    });

});
$(function(){

    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });


});
$("#fgfg").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $("#toDate").prop("disabled",true);
    }else{
        $("#toDate").prop("disabled",false);
    }
});

$("#candiwork").validate({
    rules: {
                job: {
                        required: true,
                },          
                fromDate: {
                        required: true,
                },
                toDate:{
                    required:true,
                },
                company:{
                    required:true,
                },
                description:{
                    required:true,
                }

            },
            messages: {
                job :"Please enter job title",        
                fromDate:"Please enter from date",
                toDate:"Please enter to date",
                company:"Please enter company name",
                description:"Please enter description"
                },
});
</script>
```

Comment: I believe you override the options you have set so nicely after document has loaded with `$('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });`. That's my first guess.... Do you get any errors? Did you check if the event `changeDate` fires with a `console.log("Event ChangeDate fired")`

Comment: no errors found